# I have created A new sample REST Api to GET method, Giving Consumer is not authorized to access the resource error

Tags: magento2, rest-api

As I have created a New sample REST Api Call to method GET please look below details

**etc/webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/hello/name/:name" method="GET">
        <service class="Magestore\Magento\Api\HelloInterface" method="name"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magestore\Magento\Api\HelloInterface"
                type="Magestore\Magento\Model\Hello" />
</config>
```

**Api/HelloInterface**

```
<?php
namespace Magestore\Magento\Api;

interface HelloInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $name Users name.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
    public function name($name);
}
```

**Model/Hello.php**

```
<?php
namespace Magestore\Magento\Model;
use Magestore\Magento\Api\HelloInterface;

class Hello implements HelloInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $name Users name.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
    public function name($name) {
        return "Hello, " . $name;
    }
}
```

As you can see the below image giving me the consumer is not authorized to access the resource as, the resource type is anonmoys.

[image]

Please can anyone help me to solve these,or else give me idea to resolve this.
Advance thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
  <route url="/V1/hello/name" method="GET">
    <service class="Magestore\Magento\Api\HelloInterface" method="name"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
   </route>
</routes>
```

then use api url like:

```
www.example.com/rest/V1/hello/name/?name=test
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: Have you done setup:di:compile also header will be only Content-Type:application/json

Comment: yes, i have run compile cmd and header as you said content-Type:application/json.

Comment: but no change same error.

Comment: Looks all fine, only doubts is module name "Magento" . I am not sure but may be this cause the issue. you can try by changing the vendor name.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Auth from header it is not needed.

Please flush cache using below command

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

It is working for me please check below

[image]

Comment: Getting the same error.can you please give more information.

Comment: Have you registered your module? please verify your module is active?